# Как сделать блюр (blur) css

Tags: html, css

Начал делать макет и тут в первые минуты такая незадача с блюром..
Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста[image: Вот как это должно выглядеть]

Comment: Какая незадача-то?

Comment: Как сделать такой блюр?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Ну а вообще дубликат вопроса: [Фон с фильтром blur](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641965)

Comment: @andreymal вы поддержку backdrop-filter видели? Только сафари и последний эдж

Answer (score 1):

Вот примеры подобных работ. Эффект называется frosted glass или матированное/матовое стекло.

https://medium.com/@AmJustSam/how-to-do-css-only-frosted-glass-effect-e2666bafab91
http://dabblet.com/gist/d9f243ddd7dbffa341a4